# Global variable in class shared to other instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I need explanation about code below

```
class Test():
    a_variable = []

    def add(self, value):
        self.a_variable.append(value)

    def print(self):
        print(self.a_variable)

a = Test()
b = Test()

a.add(1)
b.print()
```

Output

```
[1]
```

Questions:

1. Is it normal?
2. Why `a_variable` shared to other instance?
3. Is there any documentation about this?

**Note:** I'm using python 3.7.4 in my environment and running on Windows 10

Comment: It's a **class** attribute. Class attributes can be retrieved via `self` but not set. They are shared among all instances of the class.

Comment: @KlausD. The trick here is the mutability of the class attribute. Note that the OP is not directly setting it.

Comment: @Selcuk More exactly it is the fact that it is mutated, not that it is mutable.

Comment: @KlausD. Fair enough, but you can't mutate it if it's not mutable.

Comment: @KlausD. Is there any documentation about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when you try to set a class attribute using an instance, you create an object attribute that shadows the class attribute. For example, if you do the following:

```
def add(self, value):
    self.a_variable = value
```

You will end up with:

`a.print()` will print `1`

`b.print()` will print `[]`

By using `.append()`, you fetch a reference to the class attribute (i.e. `Test.a_variable`) and *mutate* it. That's why it is reflected to all instances of the class.

Comment: For the documentation- https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables